# XSLT apply-template does not show multiple of same tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-2.0

I'm using XSLT stylesheet to render a simple XML file of the text of Alice in Wonderland into HTML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Alice.xsl"?>


<book>
<title>Alice's Adventures in Wonderland</title>

<text>
<chapter>
<chapter_heading>Chapter I. Down the Rabbit-Hole</chapter_heading>

<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the
book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in
it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or
conversations?'</p>

<p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the
hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure
of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and
picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran
close by her.</p>
</chapter>

</text>
</book>
```

Simple stuff. And we're trying to output just the Title of the Chapter and the paragraphs into an  tag in HTML using this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>

<body>

<article>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</article>

</body>


</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title"/>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <h3>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter_heading"/>
    </h3>
    <div class="paragraph">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But once the XML file is opened in a browser, all of the separate 'p' tags in the XML are just grouped together into one large 'div' in the HTML.

Our group is obviously very new to XSL, but as far as we've been able to research, we don't tell why this isn't working smoothly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dind't define a `template` for the `<p>` element.
You effectively applied templates on `<p>` elements with your `<xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>` but without a specific template for them, the xslt processor simply applies default template wich just output the text content of the elements. This is why you got everything in the same `<div class='paragraph'>` element (which is the parent element you create before applying template on `<p>`).

I guess, you want to preserve the `<p>` elements as they are in the input, then just add the template declaration below and you'll get your `<p>` in your output.

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

As a general design template, when you want to copy an input with some layout features, use a "copy template pattern" with this default declarations which will work for any input (`<p> <citation>` and so on).

```
<!-- This match will select any element without any other template matching (the `<p>` elements in your case.)-->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- First copy the element itself -->
    <xsl:copy>
       <!-- Then copy the attributes if any. -->
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*">
       <!-- Finally apply-templates on childs, then text nodes will be outputed by default templates, and elements would go through your template flow allowing to be copied or formatted if needed (with specific templates) -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```